# Memcached lost items before expiration

Tags: memcached

Memcached continue lost items too early, it can lost item after 5 min or 1 hour.

Start: `/usr/bin/memcached -p 11211 -u memcached -m 6000 -c 1024 -l 127.0.0.1,::1 -t 8 -vv -I 50m -o idle_timeout=600`

At this moment cache size: 242M (limit 6000M), but Memcached continue lost items even with small size. Items which i push have different size from small to large (1MB).

Tried set expiration: 0, 608400 etc.

Some stats:

```
curr_items        240253
decr_hits             0
decr_misses             0
delete_hits           564
delete_misses          1583
evicted_active             0
evicted_unfetched             0
evictions             0
expired_unfetched         19528
get_expired             6
get_flushed             7
get_hits        285508
get_misses        276651
```

Maybe somebody have info about this?

Almalinux 9, Memcached 1.6.9, RAM 16, CPU 8, PHP 8.2 + Memcache.